# Craft Rules and Validation

Tags: craft3, validation, yii

Some of the changes in craft 3 have been killing me. I know Yii does validation using the public `rules` function. Here is a rules function I grabbed from the **MatrixBlockType model.**

```
function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'fieldId', 'sortOrder'], 'number', 'integerOnly' => true],
    ];
}
```

My question is simple. I for the life of me can't find where the validator `number` is defined. I'm assuming it validates using Yii's `NumberValidator.php` function but can't verify that. Any ideas on **where I can find the number validator?**

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out the answer so I'm going to post it if anyone else is asking this question. Yii accepts aliases as well as function/class names when evaluating the rules function. When using `number` you're really **using an alias** that points to the `yii\validators\NumberValidator` class. **See `yii2/validators/Validator.php` to see a list of default aliases created by Yii.**

Comment: Great that you got it solved! If it works, go ahead and mark your own answer as "correct" so that it shows up as a solved issue.